# How to keep Mysql time format when performing time math with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column named `hours_worked` in my database the format is `Time`  (`00:00:00`). When I perform time math with PHP it is converted to integer.

**So when I print this:**

```
<?=$deposit26['hours_worked'];?>
```

The output is `30:30:15` which is great.

But when I try performing Time math with another query:

```
<?=$total_hours_worked = $deposit26['hours_worked'] + $deposit262['hours_worked'];?>
```

The output becomes `60`. I would like to keep the original `Time` format. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

probably because your `$total_hours_worked` is being assumed as an integer.

try `<?=$deposit26['hours_worked'] += $deposit262['hours_worked'];?>`

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP DateInterval class.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

30:30:15 would be represented ISO 8601 `PT30H30M15S`.

```
$t1 = new DateInterval('PT30H30M15S');
```

To add another DateInterval to that...

```
$t2 = new DateInterval('PT05H55M55S');
```

we can grind through and do the addition. seconds, minutes and hours...

```
// add seconds, carry minutes
$t1->s += $t2->s ;
$t1->i += (int)( $t1->s / 60 ) ;
$t1->s = $t1->s % 60 ;

// add minutes, carry hours
$t1->i += $t2->i ;
$t1->h += (int)( $t1->i / 60 ) ;
$t1->i = $t1->i % 60 ;

// add hours
$t1->h += t2->h ;

// format as string
echo $t1->format('%h:%I:%S') ;
```

Or, make use of class that extends DateIterval, such as the one provided by glavic at gmail dot com in the comment section of the PHP documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php